# Google PageSpeed API sometimes return NULL

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-pagespeed

I am using google pagespeed api. But sometimes it simply returns NULL when I call. I am using PHP and CURL to call the api. Below is my code

```
$url_req = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=' . $url . '&key=' . $myKEY . '&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&strategy=mobile';
$results = checkPageSpeed($url_req);
```

and below is checkPageSpeed function code

```
function checkPageSpeed($url) {
if (function_exists('file_get_contents')) {
    $result = @file_get_contents($url);
}
if ($result == '') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

return $result;
}
```

Can anyone help me please.

P.S. It's working fine most of the times but for some urls like those which redirect from www to non www or vice versa it's returning NULL